# Sort a facet field by index not count in Solr

Tags: apache, solr, solrnet

I am trying to sort a facet field by 'index' and not by default 'count'. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.sort

I have facet fields such as Date, Places, Keywords. By default, all the three facet fields are sorted by 'count'. I am interested in changing just the sort on '**Date**' to 'index' and not default 'count'. Is there anything that I can do in solrconfig?

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

It's set to `count` by default, but can be customized per field basis. Based on [this](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Different-sort-for-each-facet-td3989221.html), you need to set it to `index` for all and for the rest of fields set it to `count`.

Example query params: `...&facet.field=Date&facet.field=Keywords&facet.field=Places&facet.sort=index&f.Place.facet.sort=count&f.Keywords.facet.sort=count`

EDIT: My understanding is that `index` doesn't mean `alphabetical`. It means the natural order of terms in the index. I am not sure if there is a way to do it at the query time, but if you can rebuild your index you can prefix your data e.g. `23_date1`, `24_date2` where `date1 > date2` for descending. At the client side just display without the prefix as suggested [here](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/FACET-SORT-INDEX-descending-td503632.html).

Comment: Thank you. I could have the "Date" facet field set to "index" instead of "count". Now my problem is it is by default in ascending order. How can I change it to descending order?

Comment: Both links are broken